# Unable to install nvidia driver on Manjaro because of a lot of files exists in filesystem

Tags: linux, drivers, graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card, manjaro

When i'm trying to install driver on my Manjaro linux, i get a lot of errors which tells me that there are a lot of files exists in filesystem.

Command to install driver i use:

```
sudo mhwd -i pci video-hybrid-intel-nvidia-440xx-prime
```

This command output:

````
Sourcing /etc/mhwd-x86_64.conf
Has lib32 support: true                                                                                                  
Sourcing /var/lib/mhwd/db/pci/graphic_drivers/hybrid-intel-nvidia-440xx-prime/MHWDCONFIG                                 
Processing classid: 0300                                                                                                 
Sourcing /var/lib/mhwd/scripts/include/0300                                                                              
:: Synchronizing package databases...                                                                                    
 core is up to date                                                                                                      
 extra is up to date                                                                                                     
 community is up to date                                                                                                 
 multilib is up to date                                                                                                  
resolving dependencies...                                                                                                
looking for conflicting packages...                                                                                      

Packages (4) lib32-nvidia-440xx-utils-440.44-1  linux54-nvidia-440xx-440.44-12  nvidia-440xx-utils-440.44-3  nvidia-prime-1.0-1                                                                                                                   

Total Installed Size:  401,66 MiB                                                                                        

:: Proceed with installation? [Y/n]                                                                                      
checking keyring...                                                                                                      
checking package integrity...                                                                                            
loading package files...                                                                                                 
checking for file conflicts...                                                                                           
error: failed to commit transaction (conflicting files)                                                                  
nvidia-440xx-utils: /etc/vulkan/icd.d/nvidia_icd.json exists in filesystem                                               
nvidia-440xx-utils: /etc/vulkan/implicit_layer.d/nvidia_layers.json exists in filesystem                                 
nvidia-440xx-utils: /usr/bin/nvidia-bug-report.sh exists in filesystem                                                   
nvidia-440xx-utils: /usr/bin/nvidia-cuda-mps-control exists in filesystem                                                
nvidia-440xx-utils: /usr/bin/nvidia-cuda-mps-server exists in filesystem                                                 
nvidia-440xx-utils: /usr/bin/nvidia-debugdump exists in filesystem                                                       
nvidia-440xx-utils: /usr/bin/nvidia-modprobe exists in filesystem                                                        
nvidia-440xx-utils: /usr/bin/nvidia-persistenced exists in filesystem                                                    
nvidia-440xx-utils: /usr/bin/nvidia-settings exists in filesystem                                                        
nvidia-440xx-utils: /usr/bin/nvidia-smi exists in filesystem                                                             
nvidia-440xx-utils: /usr/bin/nvidia-xconfig exists in filesystem                                                         
nvidia-440xx-utils: /usr/lib/libEGL_nvidia.so.0 exists in filesystem                                                     
nvidia-440xx-utils: /usr/lib/libEGL_nvidia.so.440.44 exists in filesystem                                                
nvidia-440xx-utils: /usr/lib/libGLESv1_CM_nvidia.so.1 exists in filesystem                                               
nvidia-440xx-utils: /usr/lib/libGLESv1_CM_nvidia.so.440.44 exists in filesystem                                          
nvidia-440xx-utils: /usr/lib/libGLESv2_nvidia.so.2 exists in filesystem                                                  
nvidia-440xx-utils: /usr/lib/libGLESv2_nvidia.so.440.44 exists in filesystem                                             
nvidia-440xx-utils: /usr/lib/libGLX_nvidia.so.0 exists in filesystem                                                     
nvidia-440xx-utils: /usr/lib/libGLX_nvidia.so.440.44 exists in filesystem                                                
nvidia-440xx-utils: /usr/lib/libcuda.so exists in filesystem                                                             
nvidia-440xx-utils: /usr/lib/libcuda.so.1 exists in filesystem                                                           
nvidia-440xx-utils: /usr/lib/libcuda.so.440.44 exists in filesystem                                                      
nvidia-440xx-utils: /usr/lib/libnvcuvid.so exists in filesystem                                                          
nvidia-440xx-utils: /usr/lib/libnvcuvid.so.1 exists in filesystem                                                        
nvidia-440xx-utils: /usr/lib/libnvcuvid.so.440.44 exists in filesystem                                                   
nvidia-440xx-utils: /usr/lib/libnvidia-allocator.so exists in filesystem                                                 
nvidia-440xx-utils: /usr/lib/libnvidia-allocator.so.1 exists in filesystem                                               
nvidia-440xx-utils: /usr/lib/libnvidia-allocator.so.440.44 exists in filesystem                                          
nvidia-440xx-utils: /usr/lib/libnvidia-cbl.so.440.44 exists in filesystem                                                
nvidia-440xx-utils: /usr/lib/libnvidia-cfg.so exists in filesystem                                                       
nvidia-440xx-utils: /usr/lib/libnvidia-cfg.so.1 exists in filesystem                                                     
nvidia-440xx-utils: /usr/lib/libnvidia-cfg.so.440.44 exists in filesystem                                                
nvidia-440xx-utils: /usr/lib/libnvidia-compiler.so.440.44 exists in filesystem                                           
nvidia-440xx-utils: /usr/lib/libnvidia-eglcore.so.440.44 exists in filesystem                                            
nvidia-440xx-utils: /usr/lib/libnvidia-encode.so exists in filesystem                                                    
nvidia-440xx-utils: /usr/lib/libnvidia-encode.so.1 exists in filesystem                                                  
nvidia-440xx-utils: /usr/lib/libnvidia-encode.so.440.44 exists in filesystem                                             
nvidia-440xx-utils: /usr/lib/libnvidia-fatbinaryloader.so.440.44 exists in filesystem                                    
nvidia-440xx-utils: /usr/lib/libnvidia-fbc.so exists in filesystem                                                       
nvidia-440xx-utils: /usr/lib/libnvidia-fbc.so.1 exists in filesystem                                                     
nvidia-440xx-utils: /usr/lib/libnvidia-fbc.so.440.44 exists in filesystem                                                
nvidia-440xx-utils: /usr/lib/libnvidia-glcore.so.440.44 exists in filesystem                                             
nvidia-440xx-utils: /usr/lib/libnvidia-glsi.so.440.44 exists in filesystem                                               
nvidia-440xx-utils: /usr/lib/libnvidia-glvkspirv.so.440.44 exists in filesystem                                          
nvidia-440xx-utils: /usr/lib/libnvidia-gtk2.so.440.44 exists in filesystem                                               
nvidia-440xx-utils: /usr/lib/libnvidia-gtk3.so.440.44 exists in filesystem                                               
nvidia-440xx-utils: /usr/lib/libnvidia-ifr.so exists in filesystem                                                       
nvidia-440xx-utils: /usr/lib/libnvidia-ifr.so.1 exists in filesystem                                                     
nvidia-440xx-utils: /usr/lib/libnvidia-ifr.so.440.44 exists in filesystem                                                
nvidia-440xx-utils: /usr/lib/libnvidia-ml.so exists in filesystem                                                        
nvidia-440xx-utils: /usr/lib/libnvidia-ml.so.1 exists in filesystem                                                      
nvidia-440xx-utils: /usr/lib/libnvidia-ml.so.440.44 exists in filesystem                                                 
nvidia-440xx-utils: /usr/lib/libnvidia-opticalflow.so exists in filesystem                                               
nvidia-440xx-utils: /usr/lib/libnvidia-opticalflow.so.1 exists in filesystem                                             
nvidia-440xx-utils: /usr/lib/libnvidia-opticalflow.so.440.44 exists in filesystem                                        
nvidia-440xx-utils: /usr/lib/libnvidia-ptxjitcompiler.so exists in filesystem                                            
nvidia-440xx-utils: /usr/lib/libnvidia-ptxjitcompiler.so.1 exists in filesystem                                          
nvidia-440xx-utils: /usr/lib/libnvidia-ptxjitcompiler.so.440.44 exists in filesystem                                     
nvidia-440xx-utils: /usr/lib/libnvidia-rtcore.so.440.44 exists in filesystem                                             
nvidia-440xx-utils: /usr/lib/libnvidia-tls.so.440.44 exists in filesystem                                                
nvidia-440xx-utils: /usr/lib/libnvoptix.so.1 exists in filesystem                                                        
nvidia-440xx-utils: /usr/lib/libnvoptix.so.440.44 exists in filesystem                                                   
nvidia-440xx-utils: /usr/lib/libvdpau_nvidia.so exists in filesystem                                                     
nvidia-440xx-utils: /usr/lib/vdpau/libvdpau_nvidia.so.1 exists in filesystem                                             
nvidia-440xx-utils: /usr/lib/vdpau/libvdpau_nvidia.so.440.44 exists in filesystem                                        
nvidia-440xx-utils: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/nvidia_drv.so exists in filesystem                                     
nvidia-440xx-utils: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglxserver_nvidia.so exists in filesystem                         
nvidia-440xx-utils: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglxserver_nvidia.so.440.44 exists in filesystem                  
nvidia-440xx-utils: /usr/share/applications/nvidia-settings.desktop exists in filesystem                                 
nvidia-440xx-utils: /usr/share/man/man1/nvidia-cuda-mps-control.1.gz exists in filesystem                                
nvidia-440xx-utils: /usr/share/man/man1/nvidia-installer.1.gz exists in filesystem                                       
nvidia-440xx-utils: /usr/share/man/man1/nvidia-modprobe.1.gz exists in filesystem                                        
nvidia-440xx-utils: /usr/share/man/man1/nvidia-persistenced.1.gz exists in filesystem                                    
nvidia-440xx-utils: /usr/share/man/man1/nvidia-settings.1.gz exists in filesystem                                        
nvidia-440xx-utils: /usr/share/man/man1/nvidia-smi.1.gz exists in filesystem                                             
nvidia-440xx-utils: /usr/share/man/man1/nvidia-xconfig.1.gz exists in filesystem                                         
nvidia-440xx-utils: /usr/share/nvidia/nvidia-application-profiles-440.44-key-documentation exists in filesystem          
nvidia-440xx-utils: /usr/share/nvidia/nvidia-application-profiles-440.44-rc exists in filesystem                         
lib32-nvidia-440xx-utils: /usr/lib32/libEGL_nvidia.so.0 exists in filesystem                                             
lib32-nvidia-440xx-utils: /usr/lib32/libEGL_nvidia.so.440.44 exists in filesystem                                        
lib32-nvidia-440xx-utils: /usr/lib32/libGLESv1_CM_nvidia.so.1 exists in filesystem                                       
lib32-nvidia-440xx-utils: /usr/lib32/libGLESv1_CM_nvidia.so.440.44 exists in filesystem                                  
lib32-nvidia-440xx-utils: /usr/lib32/libGLESv2_nvidia.so.2 exists in filesystem                                          
lib32-nvidia-440xx-utils: /usr/lib32/libGLESv2_nvidia.so.440.44 exists in filesystem                                     
lib32-nvidia-440xx-utils: /usr/lib32/libGLX_nvidia.so.0 exists in filesystem                                             
lib32-nvidia-440xx-utils: /usr/lib32/libGLX_nvidia.so.440.44 exists in filesystem                                        
lib32-nvidia-440xx-utils: /usr/lib32/libcuda.so exists in filesystem                                                     
lib32-nvidia-440xx-utils: /usr/lib32/libcuda.so.1 exists in filesystem                                                   
lib32-nvidia-440xx-utils: /usr/lib32/libcuda.so.440.44 exists in filesystem
lib32-nvidia-440xx-utils: /usr/lib32/libnvcuvid.so exists in filesystem
lib32-nvidia-440xx-utils: /usr/lib32/libnvcuvid.so.1 exists in filesystem
lib32-nvidia-440xx-utils: /usr/lib32/libnvcuvid.so.440.44 exists in filesystem
lib32-nvidia-440xx-utils: /usr/lib32/libnvidia-eglcore.so.440.44 exists in filesystem
lib32-nvidia-440xx-utils: /usr/lib32/libnvidia-encode.so exists in filesystem
lib32-nvidia-440xx-utils: /usr/lib32/libnvidia-encode.so.1 exists in filesystem
lib32-nvidia-440xx-utils: /usr/lib32/libnvidia-encode.so.440.44 exists in filesystem
lib32-nvidia-440xx-utils: /usr/lib32/libnvidia-fatbinaryloader.so.440.44 exists in filesystem
lib32-nvidia-440xx-utils: /usr/lib32/libnvidia-fbc.so exists in filesystem
lib32-nvidia-440xx-utils: /usr/lib32/libnvidia-fbc.so.1 exists in filesystem
lib32-nvidia-440xx-utils: /usr/lib32/libnvidia-fbc.so.440.44 exists in filesystem
lib32-nvidia-440xx-utils: /usr/lib32/libnvidia-glcore.so.440.44 exists in filesystem
lib32-nvidia-440xx-utils: /usr/lib32/libnvidia-glsi.so.440.44 exists in filesystem
lib32-nvidia-440xx-utils: /usr/lib32/libnvidia-glvkspirv.so.440.44 exists in filesystem
lib32-nvidia-440xx-utils: /usr/lib32/libnvidia-ifr.so exists in filesystem
lib32-nvidia-440xx-utils: /usr/lib32/libnvidia-ifr.so.1 exists in filesystem
lib32-nvidia-440xx-utils: /usr/lib32/libnvidia-ifr.so.440.44 exists in filesystem
lib32-nvidia-440xx-utils: /usr/lib32/libnvidia-ml.so exists in filesystem
lib32-nvidia-440xx-utils: /usr/lib32/libnvidia-ml.so.1 exists in filesystem
lib32-nvidia-440xx-utils: /usr/lib32/libnvidia-ml.so.440.44 exists in filesystem
lib32-nvidia-440xx-utils: /usr/lib32/libnvidia-ptxjitcompiler.so exists in filesystem
lib32-nvidia-440xx-utils: /usr/lib32/libnvidia-ptxjitcompiler.so.1 exists in filesystem
lib32-nvidia-440xx-utils: /usr/lib32/libnvidia-ptxjitcompiler.so.440.44 exists in filesystem
lib32-nvidia-440xx-utils: /usr/lib32/libnvidia-tls.so.440.44 exists in filesystem
lib32-nvidia-440xx-utils: /usr/lib32/vdpau/libvdpau_nvidia.so.1 exists in filesystem
lib32-nvidia-440xx-utils: /usr/lib32/vdpau/libvdpau_nvidia.so.440.44 exists in filesystem
Errors occurred, no packages were upgraded.
Error: pacman failed!
Error: script failed!```
````

Answer (score 2):

MHWD uses pacman to install driver dependencies. However pacman does not overwrite files that are not managed by itself.

The problem is that those files in someway became orphans

To fix this you can use pacman to install each of the driver dependencies using a flag to force it to overwrite files

The way it works is by using `--overwrite some/path/*` on a install command in pacman. It tells pacman to allow the package to overwrite any file in the given path. Or you can tell `--overwrite \*` to wildcard all paths the package wants

In your case, two packages are having conflicts: `nvidia-440xx-utils` and `lib32-nvidia-440xx-utils`

You can force install each using

```
 sudo pacman -S --overwrite  \*  nvidia-440xx-utils
```

and

```
 sudo pacman -S --overwrite  \*  lib32-nvidia-440xx-utils
```

after that you can try again to install the driver via MHWD:

```
sudo mhwd -i pci video-hybrid-intel-nvidia-440xx-prime
```

This last step is very important since video driver installation is much more than upgrading util packages